# How to reload img every 5 second using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to reload img every 5 second using javascript ?

```
<img src="screen.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: First step would be to have working HTML...

Comment: The `url` attribute should be the `src` attribute; there is no `url` attribute.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Every time you want to reload the image, you must change the image url like so: "screen.jpg?rand=123456789" where "123456789" is a randomly generated number, which is regenerated every time you want to reload the image. The browser will think that it is a different image, and actually download it again, instead of retrieve it from the cache. The web server will most likely ignore and discard everything after the question mark.

To cause the reload in the first place, your would have to use Javascript to get the image element and change the source. The easiest option I can see is to give the image element an `id` attribute, like so:

```
<img src="screen.jpg" id="myImage" />
```

Then you may change the source of the image:

```
var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
myImageElement.src = 'screen.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();
```

To do this on a set timer, then use the top-level Javascript function `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var myImageElement = document.getElementById('myImage');
    myImageElement.src = 'screen.jpg?rand=' + Math.random();
}, 5000);
```

The second argument specifies 5000 milliseconds, which equates to 5 seconds.