# Notification to the Browser so that it displays new image

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to achieve:

1. I have a html page that displays an image. 
   which is pretty easy.  [say my image file name is xyz.jpeg]
2. When the file changes or replaced with new content, say, the server or by some other mechanism the file is getting changed,
3. Now I want this modified image gets displayed in the browser **WITHOUT REFRESHING** the web page

So, kind of a notification system in which the browser is notified with new image, and gets displayed.

I am not expecting the exactly source code, but a direction of which tool that can be used?.

I have come across websocket, but I am not sure if this solves this purpose.

Comment: Your options are either websocket, or polling the server using javascript (ajax) on an interval every x seconds. In order to receive an answer, you'll at least need to try and implement one of these solutions yourself, then come back with a **specific** problem you're having.

Comment: I think the `WebSocket` is  the best answer.

Comment: Sure christian, Thanks for reply. So, your replay confirms me that using websocket it can be  achieved. I am going to try with that.

Answer (score 0):

The image can be refreshed on timely manner(for eg 10 seconds) using javascript, ie request will be send to server in specified time interval, and the image will be updated, this is pretty easy to code also. Please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572193/how-to-reload-img-every-5-second-using-javascript)

However this solution has got a negative impact on performance, since the number of request to be served is too high if the page is accessed by multiple users.

Hope this solves your doubt.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But what i was looking at is kind of broadcasting mechanism. ;)

Comment: @user3796318 go for websockets, pretty fast and perfect for your problem(if it is a broadcasting mechanism)